OnResize increases value only on one-two pixels at once in re-resizable
When I try to increase size with onResize it increases size only on one-two pixels at once no more, console.log shows width 1 or 2. With library react-resizable same problem. Library - re-resizable
function onResize(event: any, e: any, ref: any, w: any) {
    let i: number = width + w.width 
     setWidth(i);
};

<Resizable 
          size={{ width: width, height: 50 }}
          onResizeStop={onResize}
          >
    <div id={id} style={{width: width, height: 50}} className="box-border whitespace-pre-wrap break-words leading-[1.5px] absolute z-5 bg-white border-[#d9d9d9] h-[55]  border-[2px] p-3 m-2.5 flex justify-center rounded-[10px]">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-[88%]  mr-[25px]">
            {nameElement}
        </div>
    </div>
</Resizable>


You haven't provided enough detail to help. Where does this Resizable component come from? Is it yours or a third-party dependency?

Lib - re-resizable
